# Efeito waves materialize

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

Estou testando alguns componentes do materialize, por eu ser iniciante. Percebi que o efeito da classe "waves-effect waves-light" não está funcionando. Queria saber o que está acontecendo, já tentei waves-rippler mas não deu certo tbm. Também acho que pode ser o diretório, não sei ao certo.

[image: Aqui o diretório]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Teste</title>

    <!-- Materialize CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="materialize/css/materialize.css" media="screen,projection">   

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="materialize/css/default.css">     

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="MaterialDesign/MaterialDesign/css/materialdesignicons.css">   

</head>

<body>

    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Button</a>

    <!-- JQuery --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>  

    <!-- Materialize JS -->
    <script href="materialize/js/materialize.js"></script> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seria interessante vc colocar na pergunta de forma clara o que vc quer, o que tentou e o problema que está acontecendo. Só colocar o código e um print não ajuda em nada.

Comment: Estou tentando usar esse efeito no elemento quando clica, utilizando a classe waves-effect do materialize mas não está acontecendo nada quando eu clico no link, a classe parece não estar funcionando. A questão é que eu não sei se isso pode ser algo relacionado ao JQuery ou o diretório de algum arquivo estar com o nome errado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui a referencia está errada...

```
<!-- Materialize JS -->
<script href="materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>
```

**Tente com SRC e não HREF** `<script SRC="..."></script>`

> Pela sua imagem não dei para ver direito a endentação dos arquivos, mas me parece que o jQuery está na pasta de fora, então no caminho deveria ter `../`

**Tente dessa forma:**

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```